# What is the students current mark, weighted?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Good Afternoon, 
Thank you very much for taking the time to read my question which I just cannot work out!

I am finding it difficult to explain here, so let me know if you need me to clarify anything, which I would be more than happy to do.

--

A student receives a total mark based on the four tests he sits, and are weighted accordingly:

Test 1(20.0%), Test2(25.0%), Test3(30.0%), Test4(25.0%).
The mark displayed, is a percentage (out of 100), weighted.

The total mark displayed is currently 24%.
The student knows he received 60% for test one (12% when weighted) and gained x% for test two.  The student did not attempt test 3 and test 4.

What was the students mark for test two?

--

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Take it a piece at a time. If his scores, expressed as percentages, were $s_1,s_2,s_3$, and $s_4$ on Tests $1,2,3$, and $4$, respectively, his total mark is

$$0.20s_1+0.25s_2+0.30s_3+0.25s_4\;,$$

which you know is $24$. You know that $s_1=60$ and $s_3=s_4=0$, and your $x$ is my $s_2$. Substitute the known values for $s_1,s_3$, and $s_4$, and solve the resulting equation for $s_2$.

Comment: Sorry I'm still confused.  By substitute what do you mean, like make it as following:

60 + x + 0 + 0 = what?

Comment: @Alex: No, I mean that in the equation $$0.20s_1+0.25s_2+0.30s_3+0.25s_4=24$$ you should replace $s_1,s_3$, and $s_4$ by their known values, $60,0$, and $0$, respectively. The lefthand side of that equation is exactly how the total mark is calculated when the weights are as given, and the righthand side is the known value of the total mark. Thus, the two must be equal. The only quantity in the whole mess that you *don’t* know is $s_2$, and you have a very simple linear equation involving it, so you should have no trouble solving for it.

Answer (score 1):

let A, B, C, D be the scores on tests 1, 2, 3, 4, respectively.

then total grade = .2A + .25B + .30C + .25D = .24

you already know that A = .6, and C = D = 0, so you're left with

.20(.6) + .25(B) = .24

.12 + .25B = .24

.25B = .12

B = .12 / .25 = .48 = 48%

to check:

.20(60) + .25(48) + .30(0) + .25(0) = .24